# Create order with REST API, without cart

Tags: magento2, orders, api, rest-api, magento2.2

I'm using REST API with token authentication to export data from a M1 to a fresh installation of M2.2.0 installation.

Everything works fine with customers and products, but I cannot manage to understand how to create an order without creating a cart.

I mean, I already have all needed data from the order, there should be no need to create a cart before, as suggested in all the solutions I found (also in the official magento [guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-create-order.html)).

I'm following same steps in the above mentioned guide, but trying to post data about the order, I keep getting the error:

```
"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in \/var\/www\/html\/app\/code\/Magento\/Payment\/Observer\/SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php:24\nStack trace:\n#0 \/var\/www\/html\/lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\\Payment\\Observer\\SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver->execute(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#1 \/var\/www\/html\/lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\\Payment\\Observer\\SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver), Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#2 \/var\/www\/html\/lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager.php(66): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php(95): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch('sales_order_sav...', Array)\n#4 \/var\/www\/html\/lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Model\/AbstractModel.php(694):' in '\/var\/www\/html\/app\/code\/Magento\/Payment\/Observer\/SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php' on line 24"
```

and this is a sample JSON I'm using to make my tries:

```
       {
"entity": {
    "customer_email": "provacustomer@mail.com",
    "customer_firstname": "mario",
    "customer_lastname": "rossi",
    "base_grand_total": 120,
    "discount_amount": 0,
    "grand_total": 120,
    "increment_id": "200001414155",
    "shipping_amount": 7,
    "status": "processing",
    "store_id": 1,
    "subtotal": 100,
    "tax_amount": 20,
    "items": {
        "description": "prodotto mio",
        "item_id": 3,
        "price": 10,
        "product_id": 3,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "qty_ordered": 2,
        "sku": "002",
        "tax_amount": 2,
        "weight": 1
    }
},
"billing_address": {
    "firstname": "giuseppa",
    "lastname": "rossi",
    "company": "mycompany",
    "city": "rome",
    "region": "california",
    "region_id": 12,
    "postcode": "12312",
    "telephone": "1234556677",
    "country_id": "US",
    "street": [
        "via prima",
        "via seconda"
    ]
},
"payment": {
    "amount_paid": 120,
    "method": "checkmo"
},
"status_histories": [
    {
        "comment": "new order",
        "status": "processing"
    }
],
"extension_attributes": {
    "shipping_assignments": [
        {
            "shipping": {
                "address": [
                    {
                        "firstname": "franca",
                        "lastname": "vardididi",
                        "company": "mycompany",
                        "city": "rome",
                        "region": "california",
                        "region_id": 12,
                        "postcode": "12312",
                        "telephone": "1234556677",
                        "country_id": "US",
                        "street": [
                            "via prima",
                            "via seconda"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "method": "checkmo",
                "total": {
                    "base_shipping_amount": 7
                }
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "description": "prodotto mio",
                    "item_id": 3,
                    "price": 10,
                    "product_id": 3,
                    "product_type": "simple",
                    "qty_ordered": 2,
                    "sku": "002",
                    "tax_amount": 2,
                    "weight": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

**EDIT**

Using  the json in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201253/magento-2-rest-api-to-create-order-not-adding-shipping-address?rq=1) I managed to create the order.

Comment: try link: https://github.com/acolono/php-magento-api-sandbox/blob/master/place-order.php  .this will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the question mentioned in the edit of my question. I will post it here, in case the link could get broken.

```
'{
  "entity": {
    "base_currency_code": "EUR",
    "base_discount_amount": 0,
    "base_grand_total": 38,
    "base_shipping_amount": 5,
    "base_shipping_incl_tax": 5,
    "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
    "base_shipping_discount_amount": 0,
    "base_subtotal": 33,
    "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 33,
    "base_total_due": 0,
    "base_total_paid" : 38,
    "base_to_global_rate": 1,
    "base_to_order_rate": 1,
    "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "customer_is_guest": 0,
    "customer_email": "nicola@gmail.com",
    "customer_firstname": "Nicola",
    "customer_group_id": 1,
    "customer_id": 4,
    "customer_lastname": "Neri",
    "customer_note_notify": 1,
    "discount_amount": 0,
    "email_sent": 1,
    "global_currency_code": "EUR",
    "grand_total": 38,
    "order_currency_code": "EUR",
    "shipping_amount": 5,
    "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
    "shipping_description": "Flat Rate - Fixed",
    "shipping_discount_amount": 0,
    "shipping_incl_tax": 5,
    "state": "pending",
    "status": "processing",
    "store_currency_code": "EUR",
    "store_to_base_rate": 0,
    "store_to_order_rate": 0,
    "store_id": 1,
    "subtotal": 33,
    "subtotal_incl_tax": 33,
    "total_due": 0,
    "total_paid" : 38,
    "total_item_count": 1,
    "total_qty_ordered": 1,
    "tax_amount": 0,
    "weight": 1,
    "items": [{
      "base_original_price": 33,
      "base_price": 33,
      "base_price_incl_tax": 33,
      "base_row_total": 33,
      "base_row_total_incl_tax": 33,
      "name": "il prodotto",
      "original_price": 33,
      "price": 33,
      "price_incl_tax": 33,
      "product_id": 11,
      "product_type": "simple",
      "qty_ordered": 1,
      "row_total": 33,
      "row_total_incl_tax": 33,
      "sku": "002",
      "store_id": 1,
      "weight": 1
    }],
    "billing_address": {
      "address_type": "billing",
      "city": "Urbino",
      "company": "",
      "country_id": "IT",
      "customer_address_id": 4,
      "email": "francoverdi@mail.com",
      "firstname": "franco",
      "lastname": "Ciani",
      "postcode": "61029",
      "region": "ca",
      "street": ["via milano 21"],
      "telephone": "071982939"
    },
    "payment": {
      "amount_ordered": 38,
      "amount_paid":38,
      "base_amount_ordered": 38,
      "base_amount_paid" : 38,
      "base_shipping_amount": 5,
      "method": "checkmo",
      "shipping_amount": 5
    },
    "status_histories": [{
      "comment" : "new order",
      "status": "processing"
    }],
    "extension_attributes": {
      "shipping_assignments": [{
        "shipping": {
          "address": {
            "address_type": "shipping",
            "city": "Urbino",
            "company": "mycompany",
            "country_id": "IT",
            "customer_address_id": 4,
            "email": "mariorossi@gmail.com",
            "firstname": "mario",
            "lastname": "Rossi",
            "postcode": "12345",
            "region": "CA",
            "street": ["via roma 823"],
            "telephone": "3469730878"
          },
          "method": "flatrate_flatrate",
          "total": {
            "base_shipping_amount": 5,
            "base_shipping_incl_tax": 5,
            "shipping_amount": 5,
            "shipping_incl_tax": 5
          },
          "extension_attributes": []
        },
        "items": [{
          "base_original_price": 33,
          "base_price": 33,
          "base_price_incl_tax": 33,
          "base_row_total": 33,
          "name": "un belllissimo prodotto",
          "original_price": 33,
          "price": 33,
          "price_incl_tax": 33,
          "product_id": 11,
          "product_type": "simple",
          "qty_ordered": 1,
          "row_total": 33,
          "row_total_incl_tax": 33,
          "sku": "002",
          "store_id": 1,
          "weight": 1
        }],
        "extension_attributes": []
      }],
      "applied_taxes": [],
      "item_applied_taxes": [],
      "converting_from_quote": false
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: how can I display my API values as a table format. my post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/209734/57334

Comment: an html table? Please add some details in your question as of which is the expected result and the result you have right now. Otherwise it is impossible to help you...

Comment: yes mam, as you know api details like different right, so how can i display all my API detail as tables like https://datatables.net/.

Comment: Please, edit your question and put some of the code you're using, so maybe I can better understand. As the best of my guess right now, I can tell you that once you get the result you just have to decode the json string tha Magento returns you and create the proper html structure... Put some code in your original question so we can keep talking about it.